# NLog: Shutdown does not invoke Dispose on targets

Tags: c#, nlog

I have added a new `NLog` target and need to create an additional `LogFactory`. The new target looks like this:

```
[Target("NLogReplayCache")]
public sealed class NLogReplayCache : Target
{
    private readonly TransactionList<NLog.LogEventInfo> logs = new();

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds a list of the current log messages.
    /// </summary>
    public IReadOnlyTransactionList<NLog.LogEventInfo> Logs => logs;


    public NLogReplayCache()
    {
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        logs.BeginUpdate().Add(logEvent).Dispose();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        logs.BeginUpdate().Clear().Dispose();
    }
}
```

and the `NLogReconTask.config` looks likew this:

```
    <target
              name="cache"
              xsi:type="AsyncWrapper"
              timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0"
              queueLimit="1000"
              overflowAction="Grow">
                <target xsi:type="NLogReplayCache"/>
   </target>
```

and the new LogFactory is created like this:

```
  NLog.LogFactory loggerFactory = new NLog.LogFactory();
  loggerFactory.LoadConfiguration("NLogReconTask.config");
```

after I'm finished with the logger I need to shut it down and dispose it:

```
    loggerFactory?.Shutdown();
    loggerFactory?.Dispose();
```

What I cannot see is that the `Dispose` from the target is not called. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes it is curious that NLog Target implements `IDisposable`, but the NLog-engine never makes any use of it. The NLog-engine has supports for config-reload where targets are closed and reinitialized, where Dispose means closed-forever. When writing a custom NLog Target then one should override `InitializeTarget()` and `CloseTarget()`.

Answer (score 1):

As @RolfKristensen pointed out, using `InitializeTarget()` and `CloseTarget()` are the methods to be used. Nevertheless this is again an example of the curiosities around `IDisposable` of when to use it and how.